# Remove cells if titleLabel.string / cell content is empty

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following problem.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pxtY.png)

If a cell has no content, I want to hide the cell. The logic as you can see allows, that constantly 5 cells get returned:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(section == 0){
        return 1
    }

    return 5
}
```

Here is the logic of the actual table view:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.section{

    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CampusGoogleMapsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CampusGoogleMapsTableViewCell

        if let building = self.selectedPOIOffice.room?.building{
            cell.setMarkerForSelectedBuilding(building)
        }

        return cell

    case 1:

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CampusTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CampusTableViewCell

        let iconLabel: UILabel = cell.iconLabel
        let titleLabel: UILabel = cell.titleLabel

        iconLabel.font = UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 25, style: .solid)


        switch indexPath.row{

        case 0:
            //name
            titleLabel.text = selectedPOIOffice.name
            titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            titleLabel.alpha = 0.8
            iconLabel.text = FontAwesomeIcons.University.getIcon()
        case 1:
            //Phone
            titleLabel.text = selectedPOIOffice.phone
            titleLabel.textColor = HsKAmpusColors.Red
            iconLabel.text = FontAwesomeIcons.Phone.getIcon()
        case 2:
            //email
            titleLabel.text = selectedPOIOffice.email
            titleLabel.textColor = HsKAmpusColors.Red
            iconLabel.text = FontAwesomeIcons.Mail.getIcon()

        case 3:
            //Opening Hours
            if(titleLabel.text == nil){ break}

            titleLabel.text = selectedPOIOffice.openingHours
            titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            titleLabel.alpha = 0.8
            iconLabel.text = FontAwesomeIcons.Clock.getIcon()
        case 4:
            //Location
            titleLabel.text = selectedPOIOffice.room?.roomAndBuildingString ?? ""
            titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            titleLabel.alpha = 0.8
            iconLabel.text = FontAwesomeIcons.PositionMarker.getIcon()
        default:
            break
        }

        return cell

    default:
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

I think I could solve it with a simple for-statement to check if every cell has any content. Can you help me please with the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going about this all wrong. `cellForRowAt` is not the place to attempt to hide a cell. By the time it is called, the cell is going to be shown.

Do one of two things:

1. Update your data model used by your data source methods to only include the data you want to display. Or...
2. Implement `heightForRowAt` to return 0 for rows you don't wish to see.

Comment: Setting the height of the cell to zero would work, but that seems like a hack to make a bad design work.

Answer (score 2):

"If a cell has no content, I want to hide the cell."

That sentence shows a basic misunderstanding of how table views and collection views work. Table views display tabular data from a data model. If you have empty entries in your model, remove them from the model before giving it to the table view.